# ¿Cómo seleccionar columnas que tienen un guion?

Tags: sql-server

Mi tabla contiene una columna `E-mail`. Como el guion es un carácter especial, el `SELECT` falla:

```
SELECT
   E-mail
FROM
   mi_tabla
```

Diciendo:

> El nombre de la columna 'E' no es válido.

Me fijo que esto se corrige usando o bien doble comilla o bien corchetes (con comilla simple no funciona):

```
SELECT
   [E-mail]

SELECT
   "E-mail"
```

Sin embargo, me pregunto: ¿son todas equivalentes? ¿Hay alguna más recomendada?

Mi versión es "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM)".

Comment: @Camilo ¿cuál era el objetivo de [tu edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/74970/revisions)? Creo que no aporta nada, no sigue ninguna de las directrices del [privilegio de editar preguntas y respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) ni está explicada en el resumen de la edición. Por todo ello, la revierto. Supongo que tiene que ver con [lo comentado en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2965/83).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que la segunda opción funcione:

```
SELECT
   "E-mail"
FROM
   mi_tabla
```

deberás tener la opción [QUOTED_IDENTIFIER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms174393.aspx) establecida en ON:

> Cuando `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` es `ON`, los identificadores pueden
>   delimitarse con comillas dobles y los literales deben delimitarse con
>   comillas simples. Cuando `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` es `OFF`, los
>   identificadores no pueden entrecomillarse y deben seguir todas las
>   reglas para identificadores de Transact-SQL.
>
> Uso de los corchetes `[` y `]` para delimitar identificadores no se ve
>   afectado por la configuración de `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`.

De modo que, **si no hay otra opción**, mejor usar los corchetes `[]`

```
SELECT
   [E-mail]
FROM
   mi_tabla
```

## PERO...

La **mejor** opción de todas es evitar caracteres especiales cuando otorgas el nombre a tus columnas para evitar **este** y otros inconvenientes que podrían ser más serios.

La [documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027.aspx) dice lo siguiente al respecto:

> SQL Server permite cualquier carácter en la página de códigos actual
>   para ser utilizado en un identificador delimitado. Sin embargo, **el
>   uso indiscriminado de caracteres especiales en un nombre de objeto
>   puede hacer las declaraciones y scripts SQL difíciles de leer y
>   mantener**. Por ejemplo, puede crear una tabla con el nombre del
>   `Employee]`, donde el corchete de cierre es parte del nombre. Para
>   hacer esto usted tiene que escapar del corchete de cierre mediante dos
>   más entre corchetes, como se muestra en el siguiente código:

```
CREATE TABLE [Employee]]] 
(
EmployeeID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(30),
LastName varchar(30)
)
```

Y yo agrego: **Usted puede hacerlo, si le gusta complicarse la vida.**

:)

Comment: Uy, creo que nuestras ediciones colisionaron. Creo interesante añadir lo que introduje en [mi revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/74980/2), ¿te parece bien?

Comment: @fedorqui Sí, hay habido una colisión de ediciones, estaba agregando la nota sobre el uso indiscriminado de caracteres especiales. He agregado tu nota, revisa si falta algo y si ves necesario puedes editarla. Saludos.

Comment: Está perfecto, muchas gracias. Y sí, esto es complicarse la vida... al que creó la base de datos le gustaba hacerlo y yo lo sufro :D

Comment: Yo haría un análisis exhaustivo sobre el uso de esas columnas difíciles y cuando tenga localizado donde se usan, le cambiaría el nombre... aunque podría ser complicado en una bd con mucho tráfico.

Comment: Sí, en eso estamos. Dado que es una base de datos atacada desde diferentes frameworks, es complicado de realizar.